# sfDoctrineMasterSlavePlugin and I18N error "Unknown relation alias Translation"

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm working on a Symfony 1.4 application, and I use doctrine I18N. For flexibility needs, I'm migrating my database architecture so I will have 2 MySQL databases: 1 Master and 1 Slave. That's why I decided to use sfDoctrineMasterSlavePlugin that seems perfect for this new configuration. Unfortunately I'm now getting some errors with I18N. Here's my config :

databases.yml

```
dev:
  master:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:       mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db;
      username:  ****
      password:  ****

  slave:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:       mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db;
      username:  ****
      password:  ****
```

schema.yml

```
Data:
  actAs:
    I18n:
      fields: [name]
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255) }
```

In my template

```
<?php echo $data->getName(); ?>
```

I get this error

```
Unknown relation alias Translation
```

I can't find any reasons why this relation wouldn't work properly!... I found some people getting the same error but didn't find any solution...

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Do you get this error with all I18n relations? Or just with this one?

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I didn't get notification for your comment... Actually I have this error with all my I18n relations. And I still didn't find any solution to make it work properly!...

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution thanks to Joe Siponen from http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-363 (see the post for explanations)

In lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record/Generator.php :

```
abstract class Doctrine_Record_Generator extends Doctrine_Record_Abstract
{
    protected static $lastConnectionHash = null;

    /* ... */

    public function initialize(Doctrine_Table $table)
    {
        if ($this->_initialized) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->_initialized = true;

        $this->initOptions();

        $table->addGenerator($this, get_class($this));

        $this->_options['table'] = $table;

        $ownerClassName = $this->_options['table']->getComponentName();
        $className = $this->_options['className'];
        $this->_options['className'] = str_replace('%CLASS%', $ownerClassName, $className);

        if (isset($this->_options['tableName'])) {
            $ownerTableName = $this->_options['table']->getTableName();
            $tableName = $this->_options['tableName'];
            $this->_options['tableName'] = str_replace('%TABLE%', $ownerTableName, $tableName);
        }

        // check that class doesn't exist (otherwise we cannot create it)
        if ($this->_options['generateFiles'] === false && class_exists($this->_options['className'])) {
            $this->_table = Doctrine_Core::getTable($this->_options['className']);
            return false;
        }

        $currentConnectionHash = spl_object_hash($table->getConnection()->getDbh());

        if ($currentConnectionHash != self::$lastConnectionHash)
        {
            self::$lastConnectionHash = $currentConnectionHash;

            $this->buildTable();

            $fk = $this->buildForeignKeys($this->_options['table']);

            $this->_table->setColumns($fk);

            $this->buildRelation();

            $this->setTableDefinition();
            $this->setUp();

            $this->generateClassFromTable($this->_table);

            $this->buildChildDefinitions();

            $this->_table->initIdentifier();
        }
    }


    /* ... */

}
```